# DesignAutomationClient() object creation fails with System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, autodesk-designautomation

I'm thinking I must be missing something obvious, but im trying to create a new DesignAutomationClient object like follows:

```
private void runDAButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            createWorkItem();
        }

        private async Task createWorkItem()
        {
            var forgeConfig = new Autodesk.Forge.Core.ForgeConfiguration();
            forgeConfig.ClientId = clientID;
            forgeConfig.ClientSecret = clientSecret;

            var apiInstance = new DesignAutomationClient();            

            // Code to create work item will go here

        }
```

but when I do, the following error appears in my Visual Studio Debug/Immediate window after trying to execute the `var apiInstance = new DesignAutomationClient();` line:

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeLoadException' in mscorlib.dll

Am i missing something obvious? The design automation client was downloaded using NuGet so i should have all the required depencies, but searches of forums for this kind of error all say it means I'm either missing a DLL file, or the type I'm looking for doesn't exist within a DLL, neither of which I believe are true.

This code is in a simple windows form application written in C#
There are no web servers or ASP.NET involved.
The user clicks a button on the form which runs the runDAButton_Click function(which in turn runs the createWorkItem() function). That function should create an instance of the API, and then use it to create my work item.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, @jh_dempsey, do you get a chance to read some doc [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation#getting-started). Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Emma

I have seen that document but it doesn't seem to be helping me.
Originally I was setting the clientID and secret after trying to create the DesignAutomationClient object, so I moved those lines to before, but it hasn't made a difference.

Im not creating a webservice. Im creating a simple Windows Form application, which makes I hard for me to figure out what parts of the getting started I need, and which I don't.....

Comment: ```
        private async Task createWorkItem()
        {
            var forgeConfig = new ForgeConfiguration();
            forgeConfig.ClientId = clientID;
            forgeConfig.ClientSecret = clientSecret;

            var apiInstance = new DesignAutomationClient();  
```

Answer (score 0):

We need more information to troubleshoot, is it a ASP .NET core? how you are handling DI
but if your app is .NET core console app from the code as it appears.
The right way to do is.

```
dotnet new console
dotnet add package Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation --version 3.0.3
```

Code:

```
namespace daconsole
{
    using Autodesk.Forge.Core;
    using Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation;
    using Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the <see cref="ConsoleHost" />.
    /// </summary>
    class ConsoleHost : IHostedService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The StartAsync.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellationToken<see cref="CancellationToken"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/>.</returns>
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The StopAsync.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellationToken<see cref="CancellationToken"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/>.</returns>
        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the <see cref="App" />.
    /// </summary>
    internal class App
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the api.
        /// </summary>
        public DesignAutomationClient api;

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the config.
        /// </summary>
        public ForgeConfiguration config;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="App"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="api">The api<see cref="DesignAutomationClient"/>.</param>
        /// <param name="config">The config<see cref="IOptions{ForgeConfiguration}"/>.</param>
        public App(DesignAutomationClient api, IOptions<ForgeConfiguration> config)
        {
            this.api = api;
            this.config = config.Value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The CreateWorkItem.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/>.</returns>
        private async Task CreateWorkItem()
        {
            //step1:
            var forgeEnginesApi = api.EnginesApi;
            ApiResponse<Page<string>> engines = await forgeEnginesApi.GetEnginesAsync();
            if (engines.HttpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(engines.Content, Formatting.Indented));
            }

            //step2:
            Console.WriteLine("\nActiviy Start");
            var activitiesApi = api.ActivitiesApi;
            ApiResponse<Page<string>> activitiesResp = await activitiesApi.GetActivitiesAsync();
            List<string> listOfActivities = new List<string>();

            string activityName = null;
            if (activitiesResp.HttpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var page = activitiesResp.Content.PaginationToken;
                activitiesResp.Content.Data.ForEach(e => listOfActivities.Add(e));
                while (page != null)
                {
                    activitiesResp = await activitiesApi.GetActivitiesAsync(page);
                    page = activitiesResp.Content.PaginationToken;
                    activitiesResp.Content.Data.ForEach(e => listOfActivities.Add(e));
                }
                var activities = listOfActivities.Where(a => a.Contains("PlotToPDF")).Select(a => a);
                if (activities.Count() > 0)
                {
                    activityName = activities.FirstOrDefault();
                }

            }

            //step3:
            Console.WriteLine("\nWorkItem Start...");
            var workItemsApi = api.WorkItemsApi;
            ApiResponse<WorkItemStatus> workItemStatus = await workItemsApi.CreateWorkItemAsync(new Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model.WorkItem()
            {
                ActivityId = activityName,
                Arguments = new Dictionary<string, IArgument>() {
                              {
                               "HostDwg",
                               new XrefTreeArgument() {
                                Url = "http://download.autodesk.com/us/samplefiles/acad/blocks_and_tables_-_metric.dwg",
                                Verb = Verb.Get
                               }
                              }, {
                               "Result",
                               new XrefTreeArgument() {
                                Verb = Verb.Put, Url = "azure blob storage url",
                                Headers = new Dictionary<string,string>()
                                {
                                    { "Content-Type","application/octet-stream" },
                                    { "x-ms-blob-type","BlockBlob" }
                                }
                               }
                              }
                             }
            });

            Console.Write("\tPolling status");
            while (!workItemStatus.Content.Status.IsDone())
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                workItemStatus = await workItemsApi.GetWorkitemStatusAsync(workItemStatus.Content.Id);

                Console.Write(".");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(workItemStatus.Content, Formatting.Indented));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The RunAsync.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/>.</returns>
        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            await CreateWorkItem();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the <see cref="Program" />.
    /// </summary>
    internal class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The Main.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The args<see cref="string[]"/>.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/>.</returns>
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    builder.AddForgeAlternativeEnvironmentVariables();
                }).ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                { // add our no-op host (required by the HostBuilder)
                    services.AddHostedService<ConsoleHost>();

                    // our own app where all the real stuff happens
                    services.AddSingleton<App>();

                    // add and configure DESIGN AUTOMATION
                    services.AddDesignAutomation(hostContext.Configuration);
                    services.AddOptions();
                })
                .UseConsoleLifetime()
                .Build();
            using (host)
            {
                await host.StartAsync();
                // Get a reference to our App and run it
                var app = host.Services.GetRequiredService<App>();
                await app.RunAsync();
                await host.StopAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

add Forge Env to your launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "daconsole": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET": "",
        "FORGE_CLIENT_ID": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To run:

```
dotnet run --launch-profile daconsole
```

Comment: No web server, web services, or ASP involved. 
Its a standalone windows form application written purely in c#
The user presses a button on the form which runs a function.
That function is the code you see in the OP.  The function should create a new instance of the API, then use that to create a new work item

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement and I used inbuilt DI container to inject the DesignAutomation stuff. `MyClass` is your class which uses the DesignAutomationClient to do forge stuff like deploy to app, send workitems/appbundles etc.

```
    //configuration
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .AddForgeAlternativeEnvironmentVariables();
    var configuration = builder.Build();

    //setup our DI
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                                        .AddDesignAutomation(configuration)
                                        .Services
                                        .AddTransient<MyClass>()
                                        .BuildServiceProvider();




//Sample class using DesignAutomationClient via Constructor injection
    private DesignAutomationClient _designAutomationClient;
    public MyClass(DesignAutomationClient designAutomationClient) 
    {
       _designAutomationClient = designAutomationClient;
    }
```

One important point here is the nuget version of Forge packages. I used latest ones on .NET 6 console app; code ran without any issues but nothing happened on forge side.
When I used below ones, app worked as expected.

```
<PackageReference Include="Autodesk.Forge" Version="1.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation" Version="3.0.2" />
```